# FOREIGN KEY constraint fails even though foreign_keys is ON

Tags: python, sqlite, foreign-keys

When using Python 3 and SQLite3, when doing `cursor.execute("DELETE FROM my_table WHERE my_column IS NULL;")`, I get the error

```
sqlite3.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

even though I do `connection.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;")` before that. Doesn't setting `foreign_keys` to `ON` guarantee that rows in other tables with foreign key columns that refer to rows in `my_table` that are removed are also removed, and therefore prevent this error from occurring, or have I misunderstood the function of `PRAGMA foreign_keys`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you define the column(s) in other table(s) that reference column(s) in `my_table` with the [`ON DELETE CASCADE`](https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_actions) action, like:

```
columnInOtherTable INTEGER REFERENCES my_table(columnInMyTable) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

If yes then your code should work, unless there are other levels below related to the cascaded deletions.

If no, then you should do it.
It is the `ON DELETE CASCADE` action that forces the deletion of the referencing rows.

Of course `PRAGMA foreign_keys` must be `ON`.

Comment: Ah, that may be it! No, I didn't do that. Can I delete all the rows that would have been deleted otherwise manually in some way, without checking for each row in the other tables manually whether the row they link to in `my_table` is NULL? This is doable but seems slow to me since it requires one `DELETE FROM` command for each row to be deleted in the other tables.

Comment: Why do you expect the linked column to have NULL value?

Comment: It is not the linked column that has NULL value, but another column, which no other table references. I created this columns after already having added many rows to the table and now I want to delete the old rows.

Comment: You can do: `DELETE FROM othertable WHERE columnInOtherTable = ?`, replace `?` with the value of the referenced column in the deleted row. Or: `DELETE FROM othertable WHERE othercolumn is null AND ....` if you want to use that NULL column.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not that simple; in the column in the other table to which I want to cascade the delete operation I just have a bunch of id numbers which reference the `id` column in `my_table`, and there is no simple way to tell from the id number in general that `my_column` is NULL and that the row is going to be deleted. Or maybe in this case it actually is, since the rows that will be deleted are the rows with id values lower than the id of the first row where `my_column` is not NULL, but let's say the table wasn't ordered this nicely; would it still be possible then somehow?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye I don't know your data. You can post a question with sample data and expected results to clarify your problem.